# Google IAP Subscriptions query from server returning wrong expirytime, how to link receipt to actual payments?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, renewal

I have an app in the playstore for my website, that offers a monthly recurring subscription, and on my backend I am both granting that month of premium usage and recording the fact that another payment occurred whenever the expiry time runs out on the last receipt and I re-query the Google subscription to check it is still active using https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions

There are other forms of payment on my website and apps, so I found this approach was working best. However recently I noticed my system had recorded too many payments compared to what was reported by Google itself.

It turned out that at renew time when I re-query the subscription, Google was returning that it was still active but expired in 1 day, instead of in ~30 days. My system would record that a payment must have occurred and then check again in 1 day (which this time would give the correct expiry time), and then again record that a payment must have occurred when Google again reported it was still active.

For example:

1. 20th February - Initial purchase on app, app tells server the receipt etc. Expires in 30 days.
2. 21st March - The expiry time is up so server re-checks status and Google says "expires March 22nd".
3. 22nd March - The expiry time is up so server re-checks status and Google says "expires April 21st" (this is what it should have said last time)
4. 21st April - The expiry time is up so server re-checks status and Google AGAIN says it only expires in 1 day, on the 22nd of April
5. etc

I am at a loss as to why Google is reporting the wrong expiry times once a month. I do not have any free days / trial period set up for my IAP subscription. As long as Google reported the correct expiry times then I would have recorded the payments correctly. But if the expiry time is not reliable, how can I tell if a payment has actually occurred?

The subscriptions resource returned by the above API call does not return the orderId of the most recent payment. I can't find a way to link the receipt I have stored server-side with its purchaseToken to any billing information of subsequent renewal payments.

Is there a way to link a receipt/purchaseToken stored server-side to actual payments that are occurring using a Google API? How can I get the most recent orderIds?

Comment: Do you have a "Grace period" for your subscription product set?

Comment: No, afraid not, hence why this behaviour was so unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

> But if the expiry time is not reliable, how can I tell if a payment has actually occurred?

I am working on exactly the same problem and have the same observation.
It seems that even if you have no Grace period, it will behave like you have set grace period to 1 day.

Since you don't have grace period, my suggestion is to check the **newly queried expiry time** against the **previous expiry time** (you need to store that somewhere).

If it differs by around 1 month, then you can consider that a successful payment. Otherwise, the difference should be around 1 day and it's Google's grace logic at work (probably).

Take note that the time the expiry time **varies** (i.e: if you first expiry is on *21st March 12:00:00*, the second expiry can be **after**, like *21st April 13:12:32*), so you shouldn't use sharp check (i.e diff == exactly 1 month).

Here is an example from Google merchant history. The **Date** column is approximately equal to the expiry time.

[image]

---

> Is there a way to link a receipt/purchaseToken stored server-side to actual payments that are occurring using a Google API? How can I get the most recent orderIds?

You can get the client to send both *orderID* and *purchaseToken* as part of the payload, then link them on server.

That seems to be the only place with knowledge of both, for now.